# How to give screen orientations in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, screen

I have developed a app in windows Phone8.
How can i provide screen orientations for all the screens in the app.
I have refered the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx) link but could not get help much.
Will i be needing to design my whole App again??

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to specify the supported orientation , in XAML or in code.

#### XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"/>
```

#### C#

```
public partial class Application1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
   public void SetSupportedOrientations
   {
        SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;
   }
}
```